# How to correct malfunctioning Terminal in Mac OS X?

Tags: bash, unix, mac, terminal

I am using Mac OS X 10.10.2 (Yosemite)—not a server version of the OS—and standard “Terminal” commands like `ls`, `sudo`, `cp`, `mv`, `rm` are no longer recognized in my Mac “Terminal.” I face this problem after I edited the `.bash_profile` file. I installed Tomcat and added `PATH` and `CATALINA_HOME` environment variable. The contents of the new `.bash_profile` are:

```
export PATH=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_72.jdk/Contents/Home/bin:$PATHH
```

I tried the following items in order to attempt to solve the problem but without any success:

1. Restarted the “Terminal.”
2. Restarted my Mac.
3. I tried to delete, rename or move the `.bash_profile` file using terminal, but I cannot do that because `rm`, `mv` commands are not working.
4. I tried to the above manually, still I cannot do that because that file is hidden. I cannot even show the hidden files using `defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles TRUE` command, because that command also not working.

As far as I tested, only the `cd` command is working.

[image]

Comment: The problem was due to this line in the .bash_profile file (note the double H at the end): `export PATH=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_72.jdk/Contents/Home/bin:$PATHH`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `/usr/bin/vi .bash_profile`.

Make sure that when redefining `PATH`, you include the original `PATH` with it. The reason you got these issues is that you lost your original `PATH` that contains the normal locations for software.